# Unrepairable crashed MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

a couple of days ago, my user's forum suddenly went down because of a database problem. More specifically, when performing any query on the "forum_users" table, I get the error message

```
Table 'forum_users' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

Fair enough, except that this table is very stubborn and just doesn't want to be repaired ;-) Running "REPAIR TABLE forum_users" gives me

```
Error    : Table 'forum_users' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
status   : Table is already up to date
```

The same happens if I run

```
mysqlcheck --verbose --repair
```

on the table in question. The ultimate reason for the problem seems to be that if I run the MySQL command

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS
```

it tells me that forum_users is a version 9 MyISAM table while all the other tables are version 10. I finally tried dumping the whole table, hoping that I could then maybe clean things up "by hand" and reload it manually, but mysqldump refuses to go beyond the first row in the table for the same reason:

```
mysqldump: Error 1194: Table 'forum_users' is marked as crashed and 
  should be repaired when dumping table `forum_users` at row: 1
```

At this stage, I have reached the limits of my poor database management skills and could really do with some help... Thanks a lot in advance for any hints!

Martin

Comment: myisamchk -r -q tbl_name This attempts to repair the index file without touching the data file

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. The problem is that I do not have shell access to the database server, which is maintained by my ISP (pair networks). The only way I can interact with the database is by connecting to it with mysql (or whatever) or by using phpMyAdmin. I will ask the ISP if there's a way for them to give me direct access to the database files...

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-repair.html Look here in case you get shell access.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Fingers crossed for getting direct access to the database files ;-)

Comment: My ISP somehow unblocked things in such a way that the REPAIR command did then allow me to upgrade the version 9 table to version 10, so my problem is solved although I still don't know how I could have fixed it myself. Well...

Comment: @MartinHairer Feel free to write up a suitably detailed answer and mark it accepted so that future visitors can benefit from your experience :)

Comment: To prevent this from happening in the future, I recommend `ALTER TABLE forum_users ENGINE=InnoDB`

Comment: would fit better on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You could try to recreate the first row then?